# Method's returned value becomes empty after call

Tags: abap

I wrote a global class with some methods in order to write UNIT tests for them later. The problem is that when I call the `GET_BOOKS` method, the data comes to `RV_BOOKS`, everything is fine. However, as soon as other methods are called `RV_BOOKS` is already empty and nothing is output. What could be the problem?

Now here's my code:

```
class ZCL_CHE_UT_BOOK definition
  public
  final
  create public .

public section.

  types:
    BEGIN OF TY_BOOK,
             CLIENT     TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-CLIENT,
             BOOKID     TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-BOOKID,
             LIBRARYID  TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-LIBRARYID,
             BOOKTITLE  TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-BOOKTITLE,
             AUTHOR     TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-AUTHOR,
             GENRE      TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-GENRE,
             QUANTITY   TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-QUANTITY,
             CUKY_FIELD TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-CUKY_FIELD,
             PRICE      TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-PRICE,
             P_DATA     TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS-P_DATA,
           END OF TY_BOOK .
  types:
    TT_BOOK TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF TY_BOOK WITH DEFAULT KEY .

  data:
    LT_BOOKS TYPE TABLE OF ZCHE_BOOKS .

  methods GET_BOOKS
    returning
      value(RV_BOOKS) type TT_BOOK .
  methods OUTPUT_BOOKS
    importing
      !RV_BOOKS type TT_BOOK .
  methods FIND_RARE_BOOKS
    importing
      !RV_BOOKS type TT_BOOK
    returning
      value(RV_RARE_BOOKS) type TT_BOOK .
  methods GET_BOOKS_BY_GENRE
    importing
      !RV_BOOKS type TT_BOOK
      !IV_GENRE type ZCHE_BOOKS-GENRE
    returning
      value(RV_TOTAL) type INT4 .
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZCL_CHE_UT_BOOK IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD FIND_RARE_BOOKS.
    DATA: LT_RARE_BOOKS TYPE TABLE OF ZCHE_BOOKS,   " For storing special books
          LS_RARE_BOOK  TYPE ZCHE_BOOKS.           " Work work with special books
    LOOP AT RV_BOOKS INTO DATA(LS_BOOK).
      IF LS_BOOK-QUANTITY < 5 AND LS_BOOK-PRICE > 20.
        " Additional activity with some books
        LS_RARE_BOOK = LS_BOOK.
        APPEND LS_RARE_BOOK TO LT_RARE_BOOKS.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
    RV_RARE_BOOKS = LT_RARE_BOOKS.
    IF RV_RARE_BOOKS IS NOT INITIAL.
      WRITE: / 'List of rare books:'.
      LOOP AT RV_RARE_BOOKS INTO LS_RARE_BOOK.
        WRITE: / 'Book:', LS_RARE_BOOK-BOOKTITLE,
      'Author:', LS_RARE_BOOK-AUTHOR,
      'Genre:', LS_RARE_BOOK-GENRE.
      ENDLOOP.
    ELSE.
      WRITE: / 'Rare books not found.'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD GET_BOOKS.
    SELECT *
      FROM ZCHE_BOOKS
      INTO TABLE @RV_BOOKS.
    SORT RV_BOOKS ASCENDING.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD GET_BOOKS_BY_GENRE.
    DATA(LV_TOTAL) = REDUCE INT4(
    INIT COUNT = 0 FOR C IN RV_BOOKS
    WHERE ( QUANTITY > 0 AND GENRE = IV_GENRE ) NEXT COUNT = COUNT + C-QUANTITY ).
    RV_TOTAL = LV_TOTAL.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD OUTPUT_BOOKS.
    WRITE: / 'List of all books:'.
    LOOP AT RV_BOOKS INTO DATA(LS_BOOK).
      " Output data by parameters into console
      WRITE: / 'Book:', LS_BOOK-BOOKTITLE,
      'Author:', LS_BOOK-AUTHOR,
      'Genre:', LS_BOOK-GENRE.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: rv_books is a returning parameter of the method get_books, the data is selected into this returning parameter in the method, which means it is not stored anywhere in the class.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai well, okay, how can i fix it? How i need to store this?

Comment: József comment is very clear, no? Store it in your calling program. I don't really get what your question is. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SandraRossi The question is how to make the data passed to other methods from the GET_BOOKS method. In my opinion, everything is written clearly and for some reason József did not have any problems with understanding. József's answer is clear. But he didn't become a solution for me, because I don't really understand what needs to be done.

Comment: `rv_books` is just a name, it's not stored in the class, it's just the name of parameter. Even if parameters are named identically, they have nothing in common. You will do `data(books) = library->GET_BOOKS( ).` then do `data(count_books_genre_sf) = library->GET_BOOKS_BY_GENRE( rv_books = books iv_genre = 'Sci-Fi' ).`

Comment: @SandraRossi thanks for answering! I should put it inside my methods? Cause i'm not using report. All logic inside class.

Comment: Do as you wish. Stack Overflow is not to ask for opinions because each person would give different opinion, user other forums for that. Have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information about what is Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, `rv_books` is the returning parameter of the method. ABAP returns values from methods by assigning their values to the local variables that are declared when the method is declared.

OK, so how do you get the value of a returning parameter? By creating a variable in the scope where you execute the method and then receive the parameters. Like this:

```
" Declare a variable to receive the returned values
DATA lt_books TYPE tt_book.
" Execute the method and store the returned values in the variable
lt_books = get_books( ).
```

Now the variable `lt_books` contains the data `rv_books` had in the method when it finished.

Comment: By the way, there is a shorter way that combines declaring a variable in a way that automatically determines the correct type and assigns a value at the same time: `DATA(lt_books) = get_books( )`. But I decided to use the more verbose version in this answer because I believe it makes it easier for you to understand what actually goes on.